# Read a file hex data and store into a string 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hex

I have "hex.txt" file. It is some data:

> gdujdurkndvju;roaen'pefk'ojfsbfwh
>
> dusigfluyfygrleuieubhfl;wieeufhrr
>
> ygilrfreusov'rpgtgtgt[s'rgjhery48

I need to read this as a hex and store it as a string 2d array (16 column ).

> example :
>
> 67 64 75 6A 64 75 72 6B 6E 64 76 6A 75 3B 72 6F
>
> 61 65 6E 27 70 65 66 6B 27 6F 6A 66 73 62 66 77
>
> 68 0D 0A 64 75 73 69 67 66 6C 75 79 66 79 67 72
>
> 6C 65 75 69 65 75 62 68 66 6C 3B 77 69 65 65 75
>
> 66 68 72 72 0D 0A 79 67 69 6C 72 66 72 65 75 73
>
> 6F 76 27 72 70 67 74 67 74 67 74 5B 73 27 72 67
>
> 6A 68 65 72 79 34 38

This is the code i tried. I need help to complete this code.

```
unsigned char hx;
int main()
{
ifstream data("hex.txt", std::ios::binary);
data >> std::noskipws;
while (data >> hx) {
    std::cout << std::hex <<std::setw(2)<< std::setfill('0') << (int)hx<<" ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you can read the file char by char `while (!data.eof()) { char currentbyte = data.get(c);  /*put currentbyte in your array*/}`. A has char usually the size of 1 Byte. Why do you want to put them into a two dimensional array?

Comment: i am beginner can u pls show me an example

Comment: data.get(c) what is " c " is this a new variable

Comment: yes. i'm working on an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now a new try with std::string and a std::stringbstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::ifstream data("hex.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);    
    data >> std::noskipws;

    int filesize = data.tellg();
    data.seekg(0);

    // array of strings containing outputformated bytes
    std::string* filebytes = new std::string[filesize];

    char currentByte;   
    int rowWidth = 16;
    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < filesize && !data.eof()) {
        data.get(currentByte);

        // buffers strings to concatenate outputformat
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2)<< std::setfill('0') << (int)currentByte;
        // putting strings into the string array
        filebytes[idx] = ss.str();

        idx++;
    }
    data.close();

    //output to debug
    for(idx = 0; idx < filesize; idx++){
        std::cout << filebytes[idx] << " ";

        if(idx > 0 && idx % rowWidth == 0){
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

May this is what you were looking for.

Comment: some value are missing

Comment: sorry, but my c++ is that bad, you probably don't want me to do work for you with it^^. But if you have any further questions, I would like to try to help. Also I have a job and I am studying, so there is no time to do another work.

Comment: ok i can understand  i  just asked  i am a vfx artist (film fx) in india  i need to make a plugin for a software called nuke it has c++ api so that why

Comment: if i need any new help how can i let u know  i am new in this site do u have any blog

Comment: do you have a jabber account?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the bytes to an one dimensional array to avoid a squared runtime. you can interpret it as a matrix using a defined rowWith lik I did for output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::ifstream data("hex.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);    
    data >> std::noskipws;

    int filesize = data.tellg(); //getting filesize in byte
    data.seekg(0); //setting the cursor back to the beginning of the file

    char* filebytes = new char[filesize];

    char currentByte;   
    int rowWidth = 16;
    int cCol = 0;
    while (!data.eof()) {
        data.get(currentByte);

        std::cout << std::hex << (int)currentByte << " ";
        filebytes[cCol] = currentByte;

        cCol++;
        if(cCol > 0 && cCol % rowWidth == 0){
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    }
    data.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: in the output  3rd  row  68 D  A 64 75 73 69 67 66 6C 75 79 66 79 67 72 output like this i need  68 0D  0A 64 75 73 69 67 66 6C 75 79 66 79 67 72 std::setfill('0')  is needed  i am sorry i don't no how to say it

Comment: add `#include <iomanip>` and change the console output to `std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2)<< std::setfill('0') << (int)currentByte << " ";` like you did before.

Comment: what if i need setfill('0') into a array or  vector

Comment: what is done in the **output does not change you data.** so you can always handle you integers and bytes and stuff without any manipulations due to its formats. you can now work with the data in the array and fill the zeros when you do outputs. **numeric values have never leading zeros.** if you want them in your collection, it's a little more difficult and you data would no more be numeric but strings (arrays of characters).

Comment: its ok to be string array i need leading zero in is there any simple way to do it